# MessageBox in qml depends on if else in cpp

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a hard time figuring out how to make Message Dialog in qml that shows when if statement in cpp is not true.
Like this:

**myclass.cpp**

```
...
if(isValid)
{
   //doSomething
}
else
   //Message dialog shows
```

**Edit**

What I did so far:

I made this just for better understanding (not the actuall app).
I set context property for myclass and set `bool isValid=true` in h file of myclass,

**dialog.qml**

```
...
Button
        {
            id: confirmBtn
            text: "Confirm"
            onClicked:
            {
                myclass.onConfirmBtn()
                console.log("Confirm btn clicked")
                //msgDialog.open()
            }
        }
    }

    MessageDialog
    {
        id: msgDialog
        title: "Warning"
        text: "Cannot confirm"
        informativeText: "Please fill all text fields"
        onAccepted:
        {
            console.log("client clicked ok")
        }
    }
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
void MyClass::onConfirmBtn()
{
 ...
   if(isValid)
    {
        qDebug()<<"isValid true";
        isValid=false;
    }
    else {
        qDebug()<<"message dialog should pop";
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the doc here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html# . You can use signals/slots, or properties binding to achieve that

Comment: register an instance of `myclass` using `context->setContextProperty("myhelperclass", &isntance_of_myclass")`, and as the above comment suggested expose a method `Q_INVOKABLE isValid()` so you can call it from `QML` like `myhelperclass.isValid()` and use that to bind it with the `visible` property of the MessageDialog? as such: `visible: myhelperclass.isValid()`. Theoretically, that should do it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can expose a `signals: void dialogNeeded(...)` in the cpp class and connect your QML code to it (using the same context-implementation as the comment above)

Comment: I edited my question above... Can I do it somehow in the else statement or I need that method Q_INVOKABLE void isValid(...)?

Comment: The invokable isn't a good idea, as the binding won't update when isValid() changes. Here one should use a Q_PROPERTY

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that? You press the button and if the state of **isValid** is *false*, than the dialog should be appear?

You just need to add a signal **showMessageBox** to the class and connect to it. The *slot* will than change the property **visible** to *true*;

MyClass.h

```
pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Q_INVOKABLE void onConfirmButton();

private:
    bool isValid = false;

signals:
    void showMessageBox();
};
```

MyClass.cpp

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void MyClass::onConfirmButton()
{
    if(isValid) {
        qDebug() << "Working all day long...";
    }
    else {
        emit showMessageBox();
    }
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button
    {
        id: confirmBtn
        text: "Confirm"
        onClicked:
        {
            myClass.onConfirmButton()
            console.log("Confirm btn clicked")
        }
    }

    MessageDialog
    {
        id: msgDialog
        title: "Warning"
        text: "Cannot confirm"
        informativeText: "Please fill all text fields"
        visible: false

        onAccepted: console.log("client clicked ok")
    }

    Connections{
        target: myClass
        onShowMessageBox: msgDialog.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems like a good path although I cant even opet this window when I add Connections. It says: TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of null

Comment: Where do you try to call the method show()? MessageDialog does not have a method show(), just a method named open()
(https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-messagedialog.html#open-method)

Comment: No, I dont use "show" for MessageDialog... I have one window and from that window I use "show" for another one, where this MessageDialog is. When I dont have Components in MessageDialog, second window shows but when I add Components, it shows that error (second window cant be opened).

Comment: Please update your question (or open a new question, because it's a new problem) and show your current state. An component shouldn't be an problem within a windows. Its just a template.